# JUnit & Mockito - thenReturn is returning null when using on WebServiceTemplate

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am using Mochito and unable to return the mock response for the api call that is being made using marshalSendAndReceive.

Here is the service api call (where serviceRequest is of type ValidateRequst and HeaderComposingCallback implements WebServiceMessageCallback)

```
public class ValidateClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
   ...
    ValidateResponse serviceResponse = (ValidateResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(
                serviceRequest, new HeaderComposingCallback(reqId));
   ..
}
```

Here is Mock in JUnit test, validateResponse is object created has values populated but while running unit test below code always returns null response.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ValidateServiceTest {
    @Mock
    WebServiceTemplate template;
    ....    
    when(template.marshalSendAndReceive(any(ValidateRequest.class),(WebServiceMessageCallback) any(HeaderComposingCallback.class))).thenReturn(validateResponse);
    ..
}
```

Expected is to receive the validateResponse which is not null object.

Answer (score 0):

`WebServiceGatewaySupport` creates a new instance of `WebServiceTemplate` in it's constructor.

Make sure you called:

```
public final void setWebServiceTemplate(WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate)
```

to inject your mock into your `WebServiceGatewaySupport`

Comment: any code snippet please? or link to some resources?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/master/spring-ws-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/client/core/support/WebServiceGatewaySupport.java#L135

Answer (score 0):

To find the reason we should have to see method `getWebServiceTemplate()`
But definitely problem with it(you are not calling `marshalSendAndReceive()` from `template` instance defined as field in test class but from instance from method `getWebServiceTemplate`). You could try to mock it:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ValidateServiceTest {
    @Spy
    ValidateService validateService;
    @Mock
    WebServiceTemplate template;
    ....    
    when(validate.getWebServiceTemplate()).thenReturn(template);
    when(template.marshalSendAndReceive(any(ValidateRequest.class),(WebServiceMessageCallback) any(HeaderComposingCallback.class))).thenReturn(validateResponse);
    ..
}
```

Comment: Tried that but still null response.